# Django-CMS locale translation

Tags: django, django-cms

I've translated a django-cms language file in venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/locale/ and it's ok. Now I want to put it in my project folder, so I don't have to copy it each time after deploy.

I tried my_project/static/cms/locale/... but it is not working.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

please submit your translations on transifex so they will be included in the next version shipped:

https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/django-cms/

Answer (score 0):

Please see the Django documentation on that topic [1]. In short, you need to put those translations into a path that is searched by Django. This means either a path specified in `LOCALE_PATHS` or a folder named `locale` in an application in `INSTALLED_APPS` (that application requires at a `models.py` file). Note that applications higher in the `INSTALLED_APPS` list have higher precedence, so if you're using the latter approach, make sure that app is before `cms`.

[1] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations